# PHP data transfer to Jquery and print to HTML

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Havin following html register form

```
<form method="POST" id="formPost" action="check/register_form.php">
            ...
<div id="emailCheck" align="center"></div>
<input type="text" style="margin-bottom:0.1px;" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" required > 

            ...
            <button  type="register" id="btnRegister">
                Create Account</button>
            </form>
```

Then in register_form.php is checked if there is already somebody registered with following e-mail. E-mail must be unique

```
 foreach ($rowset as $projectRow) {

        if($this->email === $projectRow->email){

        // Used for sending variable to Jquery
        $emailCh = array(
        'emailCheck' => "This e-mail: ".$projectRow->email ." is already registered",
        );
        echo json_encode($emailCh);

        exit();
        }

    }
```

Where:

1. $rowset is Select STATEMENT FROM TABLE
2. $projectRow object to be compared with
3. $this->email is value $_POST['email'];
4. $projectRow->email is email row from DataBase Table

Tried to make an jQuery/Ajax check. For that $projectRow->email is putted in an array an then converted with $projectRow->email. And in script.js is called like this>

```
    else 
{   

$.ajax({
    url: 'C:/xampp/htdocs/bootSite/check/register_form.php',
    data: { test: ms },
    success: function(response) {
        $('#emailCheck').text(response);
    }
}); 

 $.post(...
```

Is this even supported? And if it's possible then how. Could not an appropriate example that works.

Answer (score 0):

You can't post to a file path as url, you need to post to a url supported by your localhost server. You can use relative paths like:

`/check/register_form.php`

Or full path like :

`http://localhost/bootSite/check/register_form.php`

Comment: tried with http://localhost/bootSite/check/register_form.php still didn't work out.

Comment: look at request itself in browser console network tab. Status? Did it return what was expected?

Comment: Unfortunateely don't know how to do this request.

Comment: Saw that whole file is linked to page but how to see if certain action was done?

Comment: if request is made it will show up with url you used. Also check console for any errors thrown

Answer (score 0):

Make a Ajax request to a PHP file that will check if email is unique. When it's not unique you can output with that checkfile the text that the email is valid or invalid. Also you need to access the file from the project root. You can't give a path like C. See charlietfl answer.